# Ionic 4 - Black screen after closing the camera peview

Tags: ionic4

Everything works fine with the `camera preview` plugin except that the screen goes black whenever I close the camera preview using `cameraPreview.stopCamera()` function in Ionic 4.
How to remove that black screen in 3rd screenshot.

Below are the screenshots attached for a better understanding of the problem.

On starting the app the background screen is white as you can see in the screenshot below.[image]

After opening the camera the camera preview works fine as in the screenshot below
[image]

But after closing the camera, the background screen goes black.
[image]

Below are the codes for reference
camera-preview.ts file

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private customizeCameraService: CustomizeCameraService
  ) {
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.openCamera();
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.customizeCameraService.stopCamera();
  }

  openCamera() {
    this.customizeCameraService.openCameraPreview().then(
      (res) => {
        this.isCameraOpen = true;
        this.showIcons    = true;
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err === 'Illegal access') {
          this.router.navigate(['/tabs']);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  takePicture(captureType: string) {
    this.customizeCameraService.takePicture().then(
      (imageData) => {
        this.customizeCameraService.stopCamera().then(
          (res) => {
            this.picture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
            this.isCameraOpen = false;
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

camera-preview.scss file

```
ion-content,
ion-header,
.nav-decor {
  --background: transparent !important;
}
```

camera-preview-service.ts file

```
cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: window.screen.width,
    height: window.screen.height,
    camera: this.cameraPreview.CAMERA_DIRECTION.BACK,
    tapPhoto: true,
    previewDrag: false,
    toBack: true,
  };

  // Take picture options
  pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
    width: 360,
    height: 640,
    quality: 85
  };

  constructor(
    @Inject(CameraPreview) public  cameraPreview: CameraPreview
  ) { }

  openCameraPreview(): Promise<any> {
    return this.cameraPreview.startCamera(this.cameraPreviewOpts);
  }

  takePicture(): Promise<any> {
    return this.cameraPreview.takePicture(this.pictureOpts);
  }

  stopCamera(): Promise<any> {
    return this.cameraPreview.stopCamera();
  }
```

Comment: Can you add me to your git repo if there is any? or can you send me the project? So i can check it

Comment: yes, what is your github username/email?

Comment: github: parrycima or gitlab: pcperrycima

Comment: done, please check

Comment: I have got the solution. I have just added ion-header{ background-color: #fff !important! } in the app.scss file and its working fine but I don't think this is a recommended solution, any idea?

Comment: Its ok. If you've got it work, it's an acceptable solution.